# Html Css horizontal unordered list 25px or so space top and bottom?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I made a horizontal unordered list and after it seems to still have the space top and bottom from when it was vertical and the dots were stacked above each other.I tried putting the margin to 0 and padding to 0 but that didn't work. I want the space to go down to 0px but everything i've tried won't work.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/guineapig101/Xda8k/
Html code:

```
<div class="ulContainer">
<ul class="a">
<li><span class="l" id="l1">&#183;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l2">&#183;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l3">&#183;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l4">&#183;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l5">&#183;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l6">&#183;</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.ulContainer{position: absolute;top: 84%;left: 50%;margin: 0px;}
.a {list-style-type:none; position: relative; left: -50%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.a li{float: left;position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.l { font-size: 100px; color: #000;  margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.l:hover{color: #9B9B9B !important;cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: where do you want the ul to appear ? at top of the screen or at top of the ulContainer ?

Comment: @guarav5430 I want it to be at the top of the ulContainer, without the 25px or so space above and below it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes because the `font-size` you have used for the bullets. You have to reduce the font size and you can use the `&bull;` to show it as a bullet. Update your code like below.

HTML

```
<ul class="a">
<li><span class="l" id="l1">&bull;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l2">&bull;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l3">&bull;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l4">&bull;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l5">&bull;</span></li>
<li><span class="l" id="l6">&bull;</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.l { font-size:40px; color: #000;  line-height:0px; height:30px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xda8k/1/)

Comment: this still has the issue, if you hover 20px above or below the bullet, the hover will be evoked

Answer (score 0):

i believe the issue is due to `line-height`, since you have set your `font-size` to so large, it is affecting the `line-height`, so you can explicitly assign a `height` and a `line-height` to your `span` like this:

also you would need to set `overflow:hidden;`

```
  .l { 
    font-size: 100px; 
    color: #000;  
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    background:#ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
}
```

This will allow you to have less height and centered bullet.

see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xda8k/4/